# How to customize information in reporting manager

Tags: sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence

Goal:
Display customized information based on end user's position.
If you have 2 user:
*The first user is an administrator and has authorized to view all sales in every city in USA.
*The second user works as a salesman in Chicago and that person has acces only to read all sales happening in Chicago.

This ability should be working when end user use reporting manager.

Problem:
How are you enable to make a filtration to display right information in reporting manager?

Later on, a new salesman being responsible of a store and you also need to apply same criteria regarding customized information.

All these user use same sql code except where criteria.

// Fullmetalboy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an answer to a [similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396253/sharepoint-2010-ssrs-2008r2-security-hole/5413908#5413908)

> Within SSRS you can access the User's ID: If you create an internal
>   parameter set to this value (=User.UserID), your queries can check to
>   see if that user has permissions to view the requested data. (i.e.
>   create a table with the UniqueIDs that the user is allowed to access
>   and join to that.)

You can pass this parameter in to your queries. Use these queries to populate the available options for other parameters.

Make sure that your final query uses the UserID parameter as well to check that the user has access to these parameters, other wise you open up a security hole for anyone who manually specifies parameters.